# Error creating enterprise search senter "The load balancer is not provisioned. Verify the load balance

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, search, enterprise-search

Iam not able to create enterprise search center site in new clean SharePoint 2016. Search service is running and crawling, and all other services are online / running. I tried to create site collection with powershell butt dident help, i get same error.

```
The load balancer is not provisioned. Verify the load balancer was provisioned successfully before retrieving endpoint addresses
```

By searching litle on google i find alot of articles telling re-provison BCS service, but service is online and running...so why delete and re-provision?

I even deleted the Search Service and recreated it, but same still getting same error.

When every thing was fresh setup, i created a basic search center, and when i search any thing form Basic search i get same error.

I can create all other types of sites/site collections, but not enterprise search.

i checked that "Application Discovery and Loadbalacer" are up and running by powershell command `Get-SPServiceInstance -ALL`

How can i solve this issue, any one experiencing same issue?

Comment: what you are seeing in the event log and ULS? is it complaining about BCS or other service application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To troubleshoot the issue, you could check the details about the error in the ULS log to check in which service application the error occurs, such as BCS application, secure store service application, app management service application, then delete and re-create the service application.

Comment: thanks for the response, i was not able to se which service application eas faulty, but i deleted all my services and re-created them one by one. And it solved my issue....

Comment: It is very happy that you have resolved the issue.